# Error al intentar subir mis archivos html,css y php a un servidor apache2 con systemctl kali linux

Tags: apache2, kali-linux

He estado intentando subir unos archivos html,css y php a apache2 con systemctl. Al meterme en firefox con mi localhost eh visto que no se me quita la web predefinida de apache.
[image: Pasos de como he subido los archivos]
[image: Esto no me para de aparecer]
Os he adjuntado unas imágenes en la que la primera es el proceso en el que he subido los archivos al servidor apache2 y la segunda foto es lo que no me para de aparecer, por si lo entendéis mejor visualmente.
¿Podríais ayudarme para quitar la página de apache y poder subir mis archivos html,css y php en el servidor?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: La misma página predefinida te recomienda qué hacer.

Comment: El problema es q el archivo index.hyml en el que vine la página de apache ya la elimine y aún así me la sigue poniendo